# Json Request from Node js to Django

Tags: json, node.js, django, request, response

I have code in node js

```
const request = require('request-json');
var dataSend = {'data': "TESTS"}
var client = request.createClient('http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
client.post('report/', dataSend, function(err, res, body) {
    return console.log(body['status'])
});
```

and code in python in django 1.11.

```
def report(request):
    print(request.POST.get('data'))

    return JsonResponse({'status': True})
```

When i send request Django receive it and return `JsonResponse({'status': True})`  and request code is 200.

The problem is I can't receive and get `{'data': "TESTS"}` in python /django. When i use `request.POST` i receive `<QueryDict: {}>`Thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.POST` will not contain the JSON request data - it only contains [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST).

To access the JSON request you need to read `request.body` directly:

```
data = request.body
```

Or in Python 3:

```
data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
```